# How can I perfectly tile two shapes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tiles

I have "Snap to Point" option enabled and expect shapes to tile without hovering when I drag one shape to another. But there is intersection between them that can be seen from the snippet:

[image]

So tile figures using mouse is not working and "Align objects" and "distribute objects" is not helping as well. Is there any way I can use some functions to tile it without doing it manually with a mouse?

P.S. Sorry if I was unclear but I hope you understand what my problem is.

Comment: This is the kind of question which might be a good fit for the proposed Graphic Design Software Support stack. Please see the proposal and follow it if you think it might be useful. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86994/graphic-design-software-support/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Illustrator doesn't have any real awareness of existing objects. At least nothing which is foolproof.

You can turn on **Smart Guides** via `View > Smart Guides`. These will allow some snapping to objects and paths. However, smart guides tend to work with the cursor position rather than on objects bounds. What that means is when you are dragging it's the cursor which makes smart guides appear and snap, not the edge of the rectangle you are dragging. Does that make sense?

Perhaps the best way is to switch to **Outline Mode** by choosing `View > Outline` from the menu. You can then see the *edges* of objects and ensure they align.

There are other options as well, like turning on the **Grid** (`View > Show Grid`) and adjusting the grid's spacing via the **Preferences**. Or selecting individual anchors and using the **Align Panel** to align anchors, rather than whole objects.

Ultimately, for exact positioning, you just have to manually take care to align non-identical items.

In *theory* this is what smart guides were meant to do. But as of AI CS4, smart guides have been far less accurate and dependable. I don't know what the AI Dev Team did at CS4, but they kind of dummied-down smart guides with that release and haven't really addressed the lack of accuracy since then.

Comment: Thank you, the answer was very informative and helpful. I have two identical objects  so in this case your suggestion to use *Align Panel* selecting anchor points worked perfectly.